# MKR1010 serial communication

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, esp8266, mkr1010

Is communication using tx/rx from an arduino to mkr1010 the same as any other serial communication?

I ask because I can't find any tutorials or info on connecting an arduino to mkr1010, but there are plenty on connecting one arduino to another.

Comment: it has Serial1 on RX/TX pins

Comment: Though you need level shifting, since the Mega is a 5V device, while the MKR1010 works with 3.3V and cannot tolerate 5V on it's pins. The UART pins are only unidirectional, so it should be sufficient to put a voltage divider between Arduino TX and MKR1010 RX.